# Need to fetch all products that have specific features with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I have a table in some cms (products) that has 3 columns:

```
product_id feature_id value
1          1          blue
1          8          cotton
2          5          t-shirt
2          1          red
3          8          wool
1          9          large
```

Each product has its own id, also each product has a list of features
(about 10 of them) each feature_id represent's a feature. Depending on
the feature_id the "value" column has the value for that type of feature.

E.x. imagine clothes, 1 unique product_id -> 1 cloth -> many features / properites like color type of material price size etc etc.

Question is it possible to fetch 3 rows something like

```
product_id value1 value2
1          blue   large
2          red    medium
3          green  xsmall
4          purple xlarge
```

where value1 is the string on the value column when products 1 feature_id = 1 and
value2 is the string on the value column when products 1 feature_id = 9 (feature_id for size)

I cant figure out how to do this in one statement, without having to merge arrays in php.

Comment: the data does not coincide. For product_id = 1, feature_id = 1, values is blue, but for product_id = 1, feature_id = 8 values is cotton, not large. The same for 2, which will be red, wool and not red, medium.

Comment: it's just another example of how i want the results. Imagine size as one more feature. The first is just a sample of the actual table structure just to give you an idea. Lets just say that instead of 8 it's 9 as id for the size feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id AS book_id, (

SELECT value
FROM cscart_product_features_values
WHERE product_id = book_id
AND feature_id =  '1'
) AS publisher, (

SELECT value
FROM cscart_product_features_values
WHERE product_id = book_id
AND feature_id =  '8'
) AS author
FROM  `cscart_product_features_values` 
ORDER BY product_id
```

Well after some testing this works great :)

Answer (score 1):

Join will work: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Products 
JOIN tbl_Features ON tbl_Products.product_id = tbl_Features.product_id
WHERE tbl_Features.feature_id = ?
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Products 
JOIN tbl_Features ON tbl_Products.product_id = tbl_Features.product_id
WHERE tbl_Features.feature_id in (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: there is no feature table :) it's just a column. product of id = 1 has many records in the table each one with a seperate feature_id hence a different value on value column. There is only 1 table with 3 columns product_id, feature_id, value. ids can occur more than once in each column.

Comment: can you post your schema? Create statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
select p.product_id
       (select value
          from product_features pf
         where pf.product_id = p.product_id
           and pf.feature_id = 1) as feature_1
       (select value
          from product_features pf
         where pf.product_id = p.product_id
           and pf.feature_id = 9) as feature_9
  from p.products
```

The query is standard SQL, so any compliant database should accept it.

I'm assuming you have a normal design with a products and product_features table

Comment: nope there is only 1 table named products which has 3 columns product_id , feature_id , value. ther ecan be many records with the same product_id and different feature_id were each feature_id represents a different property of the product and the property is stored inside value column.